# How to access multiple website using different bindings on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

How can I access different websites hosted on my local IIS 7.5 (using different bindings) from my ipv4 address?

My system32\drivers\etc\host file has my binding names mapped to 127.0.0.1

In IIS, I have the normal "Default Web Site". Its binding hostname is empty, set to all unassigned ip address and port 80. On my network, I can access this site using the server ipv4 address like so : `http://192.168.2.1/mySubSite/index.html` where mySubSite is a child folder of the "Default Web Site". I can also access it locally using `http://localhost/mySubSite/index.html`

If I setup a second website in IIS using the same binding as the "Default Web Site" but using a hostname (say "site2"), I can access it locally using `http://site2/mySubSite/index.html`.

How can I access this second site on my network the same way I access the "Default Web Site" using the ip address? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is to change the port binding on each website.  This takes minimal configuration and you can place a website on any port you want (I recommend ports over 1024...to a maximum of 65000)

For example, your default site will automatically be on port 80.  Place site 2 on Port 2000.  Then you can access your default site like you have above, and you can access site 2 with a similar url like `http://192.168.2.1:2000/mySubSite/index.html`.  Notice the port is specified in the url using the :[port] at the end.

Comment: Well, your answer pretty much confirms that I can't use the same ip/port number for different local sites. It makes a lot of sense from an IIS point of view but I thought that somehow this could be done for development purposes. Anyway your answer is the closest to what I need. Thanks

Comment: you COULD rig up multiple sites on one port using host-headers but you'd have to do more configurations for that to work because you now have to also manage the host names being linked to your IP address.  If you just want everything locally then you'd have to add entries to the host file on your local computer to direct the domain name to your localhost and then configure IIS to use that domain name as the host-header for each website.  It's really not too difficult but it's pretty common just to use different ports if you're running things locally.

Comment: I'm already set up like you mention (adding entries in the host file) and my 2 websites run fine locally on 127.0.0.1 so could you please elaborate a bit more about the host-headers in IIS? I already set up the bindings and the only proplem is accessing the second website from a different machine on my network. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have multiple sites on the same IP address and port. It is called binding by domain name.

Open ISS and go to your first default site (one that is functional) and then go to edit bindings. You will see by default it states "http: Port 80 IP Address *"

Notice the hostname is blank? This is where you can tie a domain name to that exact port. Fill out domain name on both your site bindings. This means when someone comes in from that exact domain name, it knows where to forward traffic too. If port 80 inbound doesn't match either of those two domain names, it will default to w/e site has no bindings such as the "default site".

Comment: Adding to this answer: make sure to remove the bindings on port 80 so IIS can figure it out by itself where it should go based on the header.