# HTTP 404 IIS when publishing on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

**I'm having some troubles trying to find out what to do:**

- I published a directory with some .aspx pages on IIS on :8081 :
  [image - localhost:8081](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGpmC.png)
- But when i click on a page or try typing it, i get an http 404 :

[http 404 - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1mSJ.png)

Maybe some IIS configurations, but i cant find it anywhere, if someone could help me i would really appreciate! Thank you all!

Comment: Is the virtual directory setup as an application?  Can you got to IIS, see the application, and click "Browse"?

Comment: i can see the application, but when i try to browse the folders, i cant see the files

Comment: Furthermore, i don't know if this can be anything alike, but it is a vs2010 project, im trying to run on a windows server 2003, maybe it is a .net framework problem?

Comment: If you are just trying to browse the files, you have to enable directory browsing (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: no, i want to publish the application, but my .aspx pages get http 404

Comment: i was answering your question, and yes i can browse my files

Comment: Can you check your bindings and make sure 8081 is setup to map to that app?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, i am new, how do i check?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your bindings by following the instructions in this post:

[How to access multiple website using different bindings on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990690/how-to-access-multiple-website-using-different-bindings-on-iis-7-5)

Also, IIS Express will assign a random port when debugging, and this will not work when the app is actually published.

Comment: i'm glad you tried to help, thanks, but im stil getting 404, even seeing my file on the browser and clicking on it

Comment: Can you post an image of your IIS Bindings dialog?

Comment: I discovered it is a mvc configuration problem,

Comment: i installed mvc in the server, and added the library with the .mvc extension, but the link localhost by itself is return a 404 now

Comment: Ok, you are running on the default port 80, not 8081. Can you browse to localhost/inicio.aspx?

Comment: just a mistake, i published two projects, i sent a print of the default, and in the threads i use the one on 8081. The problem is: I have a project in partial MVC from a client, it only runs on IIS 6.0, the server is a Windows Server 2003, i added the asp.net mvc manually to de IIS and now it cant find the path to anything

Comment: MVC depends on the routing config, but you seem to be dealing with .aspx files, which are web forms.  I don't understand what you mean by "partial MVC".